# Some fundamental of limits

Tags: calculus

I am studying the limit chapter of calculus...In some earlier examples I found that if a function with certain limit results into more than two values then limit DNE.

I am wondering if we evaluate RHL and LHL. They both are finite but do not equal. Then does the limit still exist?? I mean , here too, we get two different numbers.

And one more thing I am doubtful about is when should we exactly use the LHL and RHL approach.... Because there are still more convenient ways to find limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When **RHL and LHL exist but are not equal**, you can say that each of the two limits exist in that point.

**EG**

$\frac{1}{x}\to+\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$

$\frac{1}{x}\to-\infty$ as $x\to 0^-$

As a simple example of limit which **not exists at all** consider:

$\sin x$ as $x\to +\infty$

To deal with this kind of limit we can define the concept of **supremum limit** and **infimum limit** (which are respectively +1 and -1 for $\sin x$ as  $x\to +\infty$).

Comment: When should I use the LHL and RHL approach?? I reckon one is when we r dealing with piece wise function and??

Comment: In many cases you may be interested to study the behavior of the function only at one side, as an example to study the graph of a function or if yu are dealing with function for which the limit is defined only at one side (EG $\log x$ as $x\to 0^+$).

Comment: understood. Thanks.